# Is our simultaneous completion of database and JMS processing smart or lucky?

Tags: oracle, jms, advanced-queuing

We are using JMS to process messages in a Java 1.8 SE environment. The messages originate from an Oracle (12) Advanced Queue.

We would like to read a message from a JMS queue, do some work based on it, and save the result in the database.  We don’t want to lose any messages, and we don’t want to duplicate processing on any message.  In other words, we’d like the processing of the JMS message and the associated database activity to be a single transaction.

We’ve read various articles about how to do this (including [Transaction and redelivery in JMS](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html), [JMS Message Delivery Reliability and Acknowledgement Patterns](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/jms-message-delivery-reliability-acknowledgement-patterns/), [Reliable JMS with Transactions](https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ReliableJMSWithTransactions)).  The consensus seems to be to use JTA/XA, but we were hoping for something simpler.

We are using Oracle’s Advanced Queueing as our JMS provider, so we decided to see whether we could use the same database connection for both JMS and database activity, so that a single commit would work for both JMS and database activity.  It seems to have worked.

In  the code below, we create a QueueConnection using an existing SQL Connection when we initialize the JMS queue.  After processing the message, committing the JMS session also commits the database changes.
We haven’t seen this approach discussed elsewhere, so we’re wondering if

1. We have a reliable solution that works for Oracle Advanced
   Queueing,
2. We have a solution that just happens to work some of the
   time for this version of Oracle Advanced Queueing,
3. We just got
   really, really lucky on our test cases, and this approach is fraught
   with peril

Please comment on whether our approach should be reliable or whether we should use JTA/XA.

```
public class OracleJmsQueue {

private DataSource dataSource;
protected Queue queue;
protected QueueConnection queueConnection;
protected QueueReceiver queueReceiver;
protected QueueSession queueSession;
private java.sql.Connection dbConnection = null;

protected void initQueueSession()
        throws JMSException, SQLException {
    // Connect to the database source of messages
    DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
    queueConnection = AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(
            dbConnection);

    queueSession =
            queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    queue = ((AQjmsSession)queueSession).getQueue(queueUser, queueName);
    queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
}

public void run() {
  initQueueSession();
  // code omitted
  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        final Message message = queueReceiver.receiveNoWait();
        if (message != null) {
            processMessage(message);  // alters DB tables
            commitSession();
        }
    }
    // catches omitted
  }
}

protected void commitSession() throws JMSException {
    logger.info("Committing " + queueName + " queue session");
    queueSession.commit();
}
}  // class OracleJmsQueue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your assumptions about JMS and OAQ are correct, given that `processMessage` uses the `dbConnection` class attribute.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueConnection.html

So, answering your question: Yes, you have a reliable solution (assuming what I mentioned before).